# List in interface

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have interface where I am setting a list and trying to fill the list later on, however I am getting null exception in the `LoadSet()` method.

```
public interface ISettings
{
    List<CustomSetting> CustomSettings { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsService : ISettings
{
    
    CameraResolution cameraResolution = new CameraResolution();
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CustomSetting> CustomSettings { get; set; }

    public SettingsService()
    {
        Name = customSettings.Name;
       CustomSettings = new List<CustomSetting>();
        LoadSet();
     
    }

    public void LoadSet()
    {
        var detail = new CustomSetting
        {
                Name = cameraResolution.Name,
                Value = cameraResolution.Value,
       };
        CustomSettings.Add(detail);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you using this service, add that code as well, meanwhile try this
`public List<CustomSetting> CustomSettings { get; set; } = new List<CustomSetting>();`

Comment: BindingContext = new SettingsService(); and filling   public List<CameraResolution> Load()
        {
            items = new List<CameraResolution>()
            {
                new CameraResolution {  Name = "low" },
                new CameraResolution {  Name = "high" },


            };
            return items;
        }

Comment: I tried yours suggestion and nothing

Comment: I test the above code and it works fine in my project . You could post the full code which can reproduce the issue so that I can check it on my side .

Comment: if you're getting an null ref exception, step through the code until you hit the cause.  There are only 4 lines of code in the constructor, it should be simple to trace.